# How to create a slice from a single element without copying that element?

Tags: rust, slice

I have a really big struct (on heap and on stack) that I use in a function. Most of the time, I want a simple variable of that struct, because I'm doing stuff with the big struct directly. At one point, however, I'm forced (by a function signature) to pass this struct inside of a slice.

```rust
struct VeryBig(Vec<String>, [u64; 50]);

fn takes_slice(_: &[VeryBig]) {}

fn main() {
    let foo = VeryBig(vec!["Ferris".to_string(); 100], [27; 50]);

    // Use `foo` directly a bunch of times

    takes_slice(&foo); // <-- mismatched type

    // Use `foo` directly a bunch of times
}
```

This obviously and understandably leads to this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:17
   |
10 |     takes_slice(&foo); // <-- mismatched type
   |                 ^^^^ expected slice, found struct `VeryBig`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[VeryBig]`
              found type `&VeryBig`
```

So I wonder: what is the best way to solve this? I *could* just make `foo` a `[VeryBig; 1]`, but that would mean that I have to use `foo[0]` everywhere where I want to use the big struct directly -- annoying. Alternatively, I could put the big struct into an array temporarily, call `takes_slice` and move it out of the array again. But that's also not very nice.

As far as I know, `&T` and `&[T]` should have the same memory layout (the pointee, not pointer), so I would expect there to be a way to reinterpret one as the other easily, but I haven't found such a feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**You can use [`slice::from_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html)**.

> `fn from_ref<T>(s: &T) -> &[T]`

In your code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=faef7f9c0a23b8ccc020e9856a6cb2ed)):

```rust
use std::slice;

takes_slice(slice::from_ref(&foo));
```

---

For mutable slices, you can use [`slice::from_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/fn.from_mut.html). Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939974/can-i-create-a-slice-of-a-single-byte-u8) about that topic.

See [How can I convert a reference to any type to a reference to an array of length 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68564481/155423) for arrays.