# How can I convert a reference to any type to a reference to an array of length 1?

Tags: rust

I have an instance of type `&T`. How do I cast it to `&[T; 1]`? Something like `std::slice::from_ref`, except that it should return an array, instead of a slice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`array::from_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_ref.html) or [`array::from_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_mut.html).

```rust
fn example(a: &String) -> &[String; 1] {
    std::array::from_ref(a)
}
```

See also:

- [How to create a slice from a single element without copying that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55863195/155423)